# Как попасть на страницу сервера с blazor webassembly

Tags: c#, blazor

Есть приложение blazor webassembly with ASP.NET Core Hosted.
На сервере происходит формирование файла и передается на клиент. Для редактирования файла надо с клиента открыть страницу (razor) на сервере, и в браузере будет происходить редактирование.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как с страницы на клиенте попасть на страницу на сервере?

Comment: Прочитал вопрос, и ничего абсолютно не понял.

Answer (score 1):

C клиентской части WASM на страницу сервера попасть нельзя т.к. технология предполагает, что страниц как таковых у сервера нет и он обслуживает лишь определённые веб-запросы. Клиентское WASM-приложение выполняется в недоверенном окружении, поэтому давать ему какой-либо прямой доступ к серверу нельзя.
Если вам необходимо сделать для пользователя редактирование чего-то с клиентского приложения, то общий алгоритм примерно такой:

1. На сервере делается выдача модели этого объекта по GET-запросу (напр. в виде JSON)
2. На клиенте происходит получение этого объекта и материализация в какой-то класс.
3. Далее полученный экземпляр сохраняется в память как исходная модель и подгружается в какую-то визуальную часть (напр. форму редактирования).
4. После редактирования пользователем полученная модель сравнивается с сохранённой и формируется JsonPatchDocument, который посылается на сервер (напр. в виде PATCH-запроса).
5. Сервер получает документ, загружает соответствующий объект из базы, применяет к нему этот патч-документ, валидирует итоговую модель и если всё хорошо, то сохраняет обновлённый объект в базу.